# How can I change TRAMP sudo password timeout?

Tags: tramp, sudo

I'm asked far too often for my sudo password by TRAMP.

Comment: You can add you sudo password to `authinfo.gpg`. Add the following line `machine localhost login root port sudo password SECRET`.

Comment: The comment above is true for Tramp 2.5 (part of Emacs 28) and earlier. In Tramp 2.6, you need an entry like `machine localhost login USER port sudo password SECRET`, with `USER` being your local user name..

Answer (score 1):

TRAMP only asks for the password when sudo requires it to ask. If you want to configure how sudo works, then read the manual page for sudo.